# PHP: Preventing users from getting the same incremented ID

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a php web app that requires to create an invoice, where its ID must be incremented (e.g: 15235, 15236, 15237,...etc). It all works fine with 1 user creating the invoice. The the issue arise when there are more than 1 users hitting the create button at the same time. Supposedly the next incremented ID is 15230, and having 3 users hitting the create button the same time, the app will return 15232 to all 3 users.

FYI, I store the last used ID in a database and increment it when users create an invoice.

Does anyone has any solution? Your suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: use auto incremented field in your DB. In that case you will never get any problems

Comment: db autoincrement id field

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use built-in mechanics and define `ID` field as `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

You can read more about that [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html).

After that just skip `ID` in your `INSERT` queries and database will take care about that for you.

Comment: I think this is the only way. Thanks for your help.